# gVim perl tags under Win32 - should I use Perl::Tags?

Tags: perl, vim, winapi, perl-module

I am a newbie when it comes to gVim, Perl & test scripts, so I hope this is not a stupid question?

I have successfully installed Perl::Tags 0.26 under Linux and OS X but am getting installation test errors under WIN32 -- also see [perl.cpan.testers](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.cpan.testers/2009/03/msg3379420.html)

My questions are:

(i) Does VIM need Perl::Tags or can I rely on exuberant ctags to generate the appropriate tags for me?

(ii) If I need Perl::Tags then how does one fix the following issue -- many of the installation tests seem to fail because the test expects /Test.pm but gets \Test.pm under WIN32. Here is an example from test 02_subclass.t :

Current test does fails under WIN32

```
like ($todo_tagger,  qr{Test\t\S+/Test.pm\t/package Test;/}       , 'package line');
```

This test succeeds - note the directory slash

```
like  ($todo_tagger, qr{Test\t\S+\\Test.pm\t/package.Test;/}       , 'package line');
```

Will this prevent the tags file working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak to the usefulness of `Perl::Tags` (I use ctags myself, but I don't currently use any tags for Perl), but as for the test failures, they look harmless. Everything should go okay if you do a "notest install". I've filed a bug report on rt.cpan.org about the failing tests.

Comment: Thanks. I have followed your advice